# problem compiling some 'math' using LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex

Have a couple of documents with the following sort of construct:

```
\begin{equation}
y=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}}
\end{equation}
```

Compiles/renders fine using 'standard' LaTeX, but fails miserably using LuaLaTeX. (I'm using MikTeX 2.9 for both).

Any suggestions? Here is a MWE to 'play with'. As noted, the problem arises because of the 'product' inside the square root. luaLaTeX seems to be having problems handling 'big expressions' nested within the square-root construct.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This equation is properly rendered using a standard \LaTeX. However, it is not when compiled using lua\LaTeX.

\begin{equation*}
y=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}}
\end{equation*}

This simpler expression compiles correctly.

\begin{equation*}
y=\sqrt[n]{x}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

---

OK, tried

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

and it compiles fine, except I don't particular want to use Asana Math (given everything else is CM). So, for my (never-ending) edification, the * trick* (solution) hinges on using unicode?

It seems as if the problem (as originally described) relates specifically to the `\prod` operator. For example,

```
\begin{equation}
y=\sqrt[n]{\frac{x^n-y^n}{1+u^{2n}}}
\end{equation}
```

compiles/renders fine.

---

Here is what the PDF I'm rendering *before* adding the suggested unicode-math package.

http://canuck.dnr.cornell.edu/misc/mah-example.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the same result with both engines; the horizontal line over the product seems misaligned where the two pieces connect, but it's a problem with the PDF viewer.

Comment: @egreg I can reproduce the problem (with miktex and texlive 2012). And the problem is not directly related to `\prod`.  I get it with `\frac` too if I put something big in its argument, e.g. `\displaystyle\int` and so force LaTeX to use the largesymbols font for the square root.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can't test now on 2012; with 2009, 2010 and 2011 it's correct

Comment: Looks like a bug I introduced in the latest LuaTeX, why such bugs are only found that late `:(`.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Is it possible to get corrected binaries into TL2012 at some point? Or are we stuck with this bug for a year?

Comment: @Caramdir: I sent a patch to Karl, but I think it is too late.

Comment: @Caramdir: to follow up, it was too late indeed and the patch didn’t make it. Debian packaged TeX Live have it, though.

Answer (score 3):

With LuaLaTeX try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
...
```

Comment: You don't need to set LMMath explicitly, it's loaded by default.

Comment: @Caramdir: Not in pre-TL2012 versions of `unicode-math`.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: I thought that it did that for some time now, but apparently that version of `unicode-math` never made it into TL2011.