# How can I debug this problem with math typesetting?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem compiling some 'math' using LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61952/problem-compiling-some-math-using-lualatex)

While trying to write an equation it seems that the square root does not like particular elements. I tried to pinpoint the problem but I am a little stuck. After some time I could get a MWE together to reproduce the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \tau_{1,2} = \sqrt{ \frac{(k)^2}{4 k_a^2} } \\
 \tau_{1,2} = \sqrt{ \frac{(k)^2}{4 k_a} } 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The output with `lualatex` looks as follows: [image]

There are no error messages in the output. The problem disappears when I either disable `\usepackage{lmodern}` or switch to `pdftex` instead of `lualatex`. Is this a known bug, am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround?

Comment: It's a bug. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61952/problem-compiling-some-math-using-lualatex/61961#comment131578_61952

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for the quick reply. This is frustrating but at least it will get fixed at some point in the future.