# How to report a bug in LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, bugtracking

I think I found a bug in LuaLaTeX. I use the current version from TeX Live 2012.

```
lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012052410 (TeX Live 2012)
```

When I compile the following document

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k}$
\end{document}
```

it works fine with `pdflatex`; [image: correct formula].

But with `lualatex` I get [image: bad rendering].

So, where should I report this?
And how can I get around it?

Comment: this looks quite similar to [how-can-i-debug-this-problem-with-math-typesetting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64442/how-can-i-debug-this-problem-with-math-typesetting)

Comment: The LuaTeX bug tracker can be found at http://tracker.luatex.org/my_view_page.php

Comment: This bug seems to be fixed upstream: Debian's version does exhibit the bug and has "pick from upstream luatex-svn: fix rendering of radicals with old fonts (Closes: #680015)" in its changelog.

Comment: Can't reproduce in `0.71.0-2012080520 (rev 4356)`

Comment: A solution was posted here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106989/workaround-for-a-very-weird-bug-in-lualatex-math-mode/106992?noredirect=1#106992

Comment: I don't think this is too localized; “how to report a bug in LuaTeX” is of sufficiently wide relevance to “TeX, LaTeX and related systems” — in fact it's exactly the question I was seeking an answer to just now. (Yes there's an adequate and useful answer already, but I see no good reason to keep the question closed and prevent new answers, as things may change and someone may have something new to contribute.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The question is not closed, it just has an accepted answer—which is not surprising as the question is more than five years old… Or do I miss something here?

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk The question [was closed in 2013, and was just reopened](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/66875/revisions) an hour ago; I posted my comment above before voting to reopen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways.

1. The first is, as @Torbjørn T. mentions, the bug tracker at  http://tracker.luatex.org/my_view_page.php.
2. There is of course the mailing list, you can subscribe to at http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/luatex. It might be easier to discuss the problem there first, and the developers of LuaTeX are members of the list
3. There is [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), a q&a site where you can discuss the problem you are experiencing. Several regular members of tex.sx are willing to put a bug on the tracker if you can't do it.
4. If for some reason you can't at any circumstances make a public bug report, I am sure the authors of LuaTeX won't mind a private email. This has to be within reason, of course.

General rules apply to bug reports:

1. Post what you experience and what you expect instead
2. give a MWE, a minimal working example that shows the problem. Preferable it should work under plain LuaTeX, but ConTeXt or LaTeX might be OK, if the problem can't be reduced. The more dependencies (luaotfload for example), the more difficult it is to find the culprit.
3. Use the newest version that is available (if possible). Always report the platform (Mac/Windows/Linux) and the version number (`luatex --version`) and distribution.