# Workaround for a very weird bug in lualatex math-mode?

Tags: math-mode, luatex

In this MWE, of a math equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\left(E-\frac{N_c e^d}{b}\right)}{a}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I find that `lualatex` (Version beta-0.70.2-2013031016 (TeX Live 2013/dev)) produces a very strange result:

[image: lualatex]

The result is however as expected with `pdflatex` 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev) and `xelatex` (3.1415926-2.5-0.9999-2013031016 (TeX Live 2013/dev))

The example is really minimal to reproduce the bug.

The question is: I really need to type an equation like this and I really need to use `lualatex` for other reasons. What is a workaround (trick with commands) or a permanent solution (e.g. load package, add something to the preamble)?

A secondary question is how one reports a bug in `lualatex`?, (or for any TeX program for that matter)

Comment: use `\usepackage{unicode-math}`

Comment: Not reproducable (fixed) in current version.

Comment: The code now works in `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014) (rev 4971)`. (version in the question was `Version beta-0.70.2-2013031016 (TeX Live 2013/dev)`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

It should be fixed in the current version 0.75. See also:
[How to report a bug in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66875/how-to-report-a-bug-in-luatex)