# LuaTeX bug with bold italic text?

Tags: luatex

Ok, so this *is* in a sense a bug report. But I have failed at going through the regular channels (cf. [How to report a bug in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66875/how-to-report-a-bug-in-luatex)). The bug tracker never sent me a confirmation e-mail for an account, subscribing to the mailing list requires moderator approval, which I haven't received yet, and the LuaTeX maintainers don't put any contact info on the LuaTeX site. It shouldn't be that hard to be able to report a bug ... So I'm doing it here. The question can be closed as soon as one of the LuaTeX maintainers acknowledges the report.

The space around a bold italic character (both before and after) is too large in LuaLaTeX. MWE and picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
    [
        Path = C:/Windows/Fonts/,
        Extension = .otf,
        UprightFont = LinLibertine_R,
        BoldFont = LinLibertine_RZ,
        ItalicFont = LinLibertine_RI,
        BoldItalicFont = LinLibertine_RZI
    ]{libertine}

\begin{document}
\noindent dad \textit{dad}\\
d\textbf{a}d \textit{d\textbf{a}d}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is not there when compiling with XeLaTeX:

[image]

Comment: Not a luatex bug (afaics it does not occur with Plain). Could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/112), so with some luck it might vanish if you update to the development version. (I’ll test it later.) Btw. the issue tracker for the font loader port is at https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload

Comment: "update to the development version"? Of ... ?

Comment: Presumably `luaotfload`.

Comment: @jon    exactly that.

Comment: The italic correction is inserted when it shouldn't, because `\fontdimen1` is always zero. So this is exactly the issue pointed to by phg. The heuristic for inserting the italic correction when `\textXY` commands are used is that it's inserted when `\fontdimen1` changes from zero to non zero or conversely; the parameter, in standard TeX fonts, contains the slant per point of a font; XeTeX sets it, `luaotfload` doesn't.

Comment: @egreg Correct. This was an oversight in the font loader which got by Hans probably because Context doesn’t use those values. It’s been fixed already and will ship with the next version of Luaotfload.

Comment: @phg I hope that the next version will supply all `\fontdimen`'s from 1 to 7. The code for `\maybe@ic` uses `\fontdimen1`, but I'm pretty sure there's LaTeX code around that uses `\fontdimen2`, `\fontdimen3` and `\fontdimen4`. Since `\fontdimen5` and `\fontdimen6` refer to the ex and em respectively and `\fontdimen7` can be taken as 1/3 of `\fontdimen2` without great loss of generality, I can think it's not very difficult.

Comment: @egreg These parameters [are already being set](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/a047f7b3c164f69b0713ee781aeefd07a27e8c61/luaotfload-merged.lua#L3854), just the slant per point dimension used to yield zero due to a rounding mistake.

Comment: If a font is loaded you can check the values like so: ``\directlua {inspect (font.getfont (font.current ()).parameters)}
``. (The field identifiers are documented in the Luatex reference.)

Comment: Just checked on my dev box, the problem seems to be gone: http://i.imgur.com/bn1ZeEW.png

Comment: List subscription normally doesn't need moderator approval - fix your mail problems.

Comment: According to the dev-luatex mailing list site, "your subscription request may have to be first confirmed by you via email, or approved by the list moderator". If you can inform me what the "mail problems" are that required my subscription to be approved by the moderator, I'd be happy to attempt to fix them.

Comment: bug fixed according to the comments