# Where are LaTeX-related bug trackers located? Where do I report `{pdf,lua,xe}latex` issues?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, bugtracking

Following up this question:

- **[Is it ImageMagick's fault or pdflatex's that some JPEGs aren't working?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243753/8747)**

I now want to submit a bug report. However, I'm a bit confused where exactly I should do this.

Because I am, being a rather greenhornish LaTeX Newbie (having been entangled into this strange technology which is so beautifully typesetting my documents only by the power of `pandoc`), I am not at all familiar with the conventions and enviroments of the (different?) LaTeX (sub-)communiti(es).

Not having much clues about how the different engines of LaTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX relate to each other (or not), how and by which groups of people they are maintained, and how the PDF generators `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex` and their respective developers fit into the overall picture, I want to get enlightenment about the following:

- Where do I find an official bug tracker for each of the `{pdf,xe,lua}latex` components/commands? *(Update: I meanwhile found the [tracker for LuaTeX](http://tracker.luatex.org/my_view_page.php)...)*
- Do I have to report it to each of these three separately? If so, can I link to this website and my original question?
- Maybe this isn't even a bug for these three? Maybe it is caused by the `graphicx` package (because it is related to embedding a JPEG file into a PDF document)? Can someone tell me, if this is the case?

From reading the documentation for some packages I noticed that most package maintainers seem to provide email addresses to report bugs to. But how is that for `{pdf,xe,lua}latex` ?

Even more "meta" question:

> Shouldn't there be some central point on SX, maybe a "community" maintained question with an appropriate answer, which summarizes all resources related to bug reporting and tracking? (I didn't even find a tag named [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) or [bugreports](/questions/tagged/bugreports) or [bugtracking](/questions/tagged/bugtracking) or similar. At least newbies like me could then easily be pointed to that spot or find it by themselves when they need it...

Comment: For packages and non-standard classes etc., search `http://ctan.org/` to figure out whether a package is maintained and, if so, by who. If it has a maintainer, the documentation should give contact details. In some cases, they may be out of date. In some of those cases, CTAN will have up to date information. [Some of my packages are in this category. Others are in the first category.] There are also mailing lists e.g. TeX Live provides [this list](https://www.tug.org/texlive/lists.html) via the TeX User Group.

Comment: You can also search for engines etc. on CTAN e.g. [pdfTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex).

Comment: See [How to report a bug in LuaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66875)