# Problems with largesymbols in mathptmx and LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem compiling some ‘math’ using LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61952/problem-compiling-some-math-using-lualatex)

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lualatex-math}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic, Ligatures=TeX,
    Scale=1,
    ItalicFont={SabonNext LT Italic},
    SmallCapsFont={SabonNextLT-RegularSC},
    BoldFont={SabonNext LT Bold}
    ]{SabonNext LT Regular}

%\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
P_{M}\le 4\left( {1-\frac{M_1 +M_2 }{2M}} \right)Q\left[ {\sqrt{\frac{3 \log_{2}M}{\frac{M_1^2 +M_2^2 }{2}-1}\frac{E_{b}}{N_{0}}}} \right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The output has a very big black square. There is not problem with LaTeX (of course, it is necessary to modify the code).

Anyone know whats happening?

Comment: It's probably this bug: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61952/problem-compiling-some-math-using-lualatex

Comment: May be. In the older luatex version there was not this problem. Thanks.